# Blender 2.8 - Sprinkles particle are not visible when rendered

Tags: modeling, particles

I just started learning Blender, so I'm following the donuts tutorial from Blender Guru. Unfortunately, I'm stuck at part 7 on rendering Sprinkles.

My problem is, the Sprinkles is visible in my viewport :

[image: Sprinkles visible in viewport]

However, when I render it, the sprinkles are gone :

[image]

My Blender file can be downloaded [here](https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/5860/).

Any help is appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently this is the issue from older version of Blender 2.8 and has been fixed on the latest update (at least when I tested on commit [d3870471](https://builder.blender.org/download/blender-2.80-d3870471edd7-linux-glibc224-x86_64.tar.bz2), 2019-02-12).

Answer (score 3):

I think you need to click the camera icon next to the Sprinkle collection for it to show up in your render

Answer (score 0):

Still the same behaviour in the build released today (2019-3-14), but there is a solution.
I see you've created a collection for the sprinkles to act as a group in the particle emitter. That collection needs to be set to Renderable (the camera icon) to work in the particle renderer. However, if you put that one INSIDE another collection (I made one called 'Sprinkles Vis') and turn the camera icon off for that one instead, ONLY the particle system ones end up rendering.

Settings:
[image: Blender collection render settings]

Render:
[image: Render result]

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue and i just clicked the camera icon at the outline in order to be rendered, its a strange behavier but its works. Just be careful of the final render put your collection render partycle away from the frame.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by un-selecting the box which is exclude from view layer[image]

The Empty checkbox in this image.